# SwiftUI - adding an extra row in a list every 4 rows

Tags: swift, swiftui

In my code I display numbers in a list. User can choose the grouping method and the numbers will be put into sections accordingly (either groups of 5 elements or odd/even). Now, I would like to add a green row after 4*n elements where n=1,2,3,.. as seen from the UI perspective (not the perspective of the data source !). So after the fourth row, a green row should follow. After eighth row, a green row should follow etc.

In my current code this works for the groups of 5 elements but does not work for the odd/even variant. The problem seems to be in the indexes because they don't depend on the actual placement.
I know this seems to sound a bit complicated but maybe someone has an idea how to approach the problem, ideally in some scalable way so that if I add a third grouping method in the future it will all also work.

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var myViewModel = MyViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button {
                myViewModel.groupStrategy.send(myViewModel.groupStrategy.value == .multiplesOfFive ? .oddEven : .multiplesOfFive)
            } label: {
                Text("Toggle grouping strategy")
            }

            List() {
                ForEach(myViewModel.numOfSections, id:\.self) { sectNum in
                    Section("Sc \(sectNum)") {
                        ForEach(Array(myViewModel.nums.enumerated()), id: \.offset) { idx, element in
                            let _ = print("Sc \(sectNum) \(idx) \(element)")
                            if myViewModel.shouldSkipNumberInThisSection(number: element, sectionNumber: sectNum) {
                                EmptyView()
                            } else {
                                Text(element.description + " idx: " + idx.description)
                                if idx > 0 && (idx+1) % 4 == 0 {
                                    Color.green
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

class MyViewModel: ObservableObject {
    enum GroupStrategy {
        case multiplesOfFive
        case oddEven
    }
    
    @Published var nums: [Int]
    @Published var numOfSections: [Int] = []
    var groupStrategy = CurrentValueSubject<GroupStrategy, Never>(.multiplesOfFive)
    private var cancellables: Set<AnyCancellable> = []
    
    func shouldSkipNumberInThisSection(number: Int, sectionNumber: Int) -> Bool {
        switch groupStrategy.value {
        case .multiplesOfFive:
            return number >= sectionNumber * 5 || number < (sectionNumber-1) * 5
        case .oddEven:
            return sectionNumber == 0 ? (number % 2) == 0 : (number % 2) != 0
        }
    }
    
    func shouldPutGreenRow() -> Bool {
        return false
    }
    
    init() {
        self.nums = []
        let numbers: [Int] = Array(3...27)
  
        self.nums = numbers
        self.numOfSections = Array(1..<Int(nums.count / 5)+1)
        
        groupStrategy.sink { strategy in
            switch self.groupStrategy.value {
            case .multiplesOfFive:
                self.numOfSections = Array(1..<Int(self.nums.count / 5)+1)
            case .oddEven:
                self.numOfSections = Array(0..<2)
            }
        }.store(in: &cancellables)

    }
}
```

For the multiplesOfFive group - OK:
[image: multiplesOfFive]

For the odd/even group - NOT OK:
[image]

[image]

In the odd/even group, the green row should appear after numbers 9, 17, 25, 8, 16, 24. Instead, it appears only in the group of even numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is not working for the odd/even section because, for each section, you are iterating over all numbers and re-creating the indexes (or `idx` in your code).

So, the condition `if idx > 0 && (idx+1) % 4 == 0` is good for the multiples of five, instead for odd/even it should be `if idx > 0 && (idx + sectNum + 2) % 8 == 0`. However, if you just add this condition to the view, it gets less scalable, as you will need to create new conditions for each different grouping.

I have thought of an alternative to your View Model using a dictionary within a dictionary, to store the sections, the indexes and the values, with no repeated entries.

With this approach, the view model gets a little bit more complicated, but the underlying data is the same, and the view is scalable: if you create a new `GroupingStrategy`, you don't need to change the view.

Here's the code with comments, I hope it might help you:

A bold view model:

```
class MyViewModel: ObservableObject {

    // Create raw values and conform to CaseIterable,
    // so you don't need to change the view when creating new strategies
    enum GroupStrategy: String, CaseIterable {
        case multiplesOfFive = "Groups of 5 items"
        case oddEven = "Odd vs. even"
    }
    
    // This is the underlying data: no changes
    @Published var nums = Array(3...27)
    
    // This is where the sections are stored: a dictionary that
    // includes the numbers within and their position in the final sequence.
    @Published var sequence = [Int:[Int:Int]]()
    // It can work with any type of underlying data, not just Int.
    // For example, if the data is of type MyModel, this variable can be of type
    // [Int:[Int:MyModel]]
    
    @Published var groupStrategy = GroupStrategy.multiplesOfFive {
        didSet {
            
            // Will rebuild the dictionary every time the grouping changes
            rebuildGroupStrategy()
        }
    }
    
    // Extract all the sections for the current strategy
    var sections: [Int] {
        Array(Set(sequence.keys)).sorted()
    }
    
    // Extract all the numbers for a specific section: the key of
    // the dictionary is the index in the sequence
    func numsInSection(_ section: Int) -> [Int:Int] {
        return sequence[section] ?? [:]
    }
    
    // Define the strategies in the Enum, then here...
    var arrayOfSections: [Int] {
        switch groupStrategy {
        case .multiplesOfFive:
            return Array(1..<Int(nums.count / 5) + 1)
        case .oddEven:
            return [0, 1]
        }
    }

    // ... and here
    func isIncludedInSection(number: Int, section: Int) -> Bool {
        switch groupStrategy {
        case .multiplesOfFive:
            return number < section * 5 && number >= (section - 1) * 5
        case .oddEven:
            return section == 0 ? (number % 2) != 0 : (number % 2) == 0
        }
    }
    
    // When you need to set a new strategy
    func rebuildGroupStrategy() {
        sequence = [:]
        
        var prog = 0
        
        // Create the sequence, which will not contain repeated elements
        arrayOfSections.forEach { section in
            sequence[section] = [:]
            nums.forEach { number in
                if isIncludedInSection(number: number, section: section) {
                    sequence[section]?[prog] = number
                    prog += 1
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    init() {
        rebuildGroupStrategy()
    }
}
```

A simpler view:

```
struct MyView: View {
    @StateObject var myViewModel = MyViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {

            // Use a Picker for scalability
            Picker("Group by:", selection: $myViewModel.groupStrategy) {
                ForEach(MyViewModel.GroupStrategy.allCases, id: \.self) { item in
                    Text(item.rawValue)
                }
            }

            List() {
                
                // Iterate over the sections
                ForEach(myViewModel.sections, id:\.self) { sectNum in
                    Section("Sc \(sectNum)") {
                        
                        let numbers = myViewModel.numsInSection(sectNum)
                        
                        // Iterate only over the numbers of each section
                        ForEach(numbers.keys.sorted(), id: \.self) { index in
                            
                            Text("\(numbers[index] ?? 0), Index = \(index)")
                            
                            // Same condition ever: paint it green after every 4th row
                            if (index + 1) % 4 == 0 {
                                Color.green
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, that's exactly what I needed, nice and clean solution !